# Calculate Area between $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(2x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $A$ be the area of region $R$ bounded by $y = \sin(x)$ and $y = \sin(2x)$ over $[0,\pi]$. What is the area of $A$?

Here's some work that I did:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\sin(2x) - \sin(x)\mathrm{d}x + \int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\pi}\sin(x) - \sin(2x)\mathrm{d}x$$

where $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is where the graphs intersect. I ultimately got $A = \pi$.

Can someone check my answer? Thank you

Comment: Can you show how you arrived at $A=\pi$?

Comment: We have

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/{3}}\sin(2x) - \sin(x)\mathrm{d}x =\left[-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}+\cos(x)\right]_{x=0}^{x=\pi/3}=\left(\frac14 + \frac 12\right)-\left(-\frac12+1\right)=\frac14$$

and a similar calculation yields

$$\int_{\pi/{3}}^{\pi}\sin(x) - \sin(2x)\mathrm{d}x=\frac94.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A_{1} = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} (sin(2x)-sin(x)) dx$$

$$A_{1} = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} sin(2x) dx - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} sin(x) dx$$

$$A_{1} = \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$$

$$A_{2} = \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\pi} (sin(x)-sin(2x)) dx$$

$$A_{2} = \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\pi} sin(x) dx - \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\pi} sin(2x) dx$$

$$A_{2} = \frac{3}{2} - \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right) = \frac{9}{4}$$

$$A = A_{1} + A_{2} = \frac{5}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @JorgeRael:  $5/2$

[image]